# Relative cup product commute with restriction operator

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

This is a followup to my previous question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1536537/construction-of-a-relative-cup-product-hpx-a-otimes-hqx-b-to-hp-q).

Let $A$ and $B$ be subspaces of a space $X$. We have the relative cup product$$H^p(X, A) \otimes H^q(X, B) \to H^{p+q}(X, A \cup B).$$How do I see that the following diagram is commutative?$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
H^q(X, A) \otimes H^q(X, B) @>>> H^{p+q}(X, A \cup B)\\
@VVV     @VVV     \\
H^p(X) \otimes H^q(X) @>>> H^{p+q}(X)
\end{CD}
$$The horizontal arrows are cup products; the vertical arrows are induced from $X \to (X, A)$, and so forth. Here, we take cohomology with coefficients in a commutative ring $R$ and we write $\otimes$ for $\otimes_R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's completely immediate from the definition of the relative cup-product (cf. [the answer to your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1536552/10014)). The relative cup-product is *defined* as the map induced in cohomology by the unique map that makes the following diagram commute (it's the upper horizontal one, the second horizontal map is a quasi-isomorphism so you can invert it in cohomology):
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
C^p(X,A) \otimes C^q(X,B) @>{\smile}>> C^{p+q}(X, A+B) @<{\sim}<< C^{p+q}(X, A \cup B) \\
@VVV @VVV @VVV \\
C^p(X) \otimes C^q(X) @>{\smile}>> C^{p+q}(X) @<{=}<< C^{p+q}(X)
\end{CD}$$
and so the diagram in cohomology commutes too.