# $X$ has a basepoint $* \in A \cap B$, commuting diagram involving relative cup product.

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

This is a followup to my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1536550/relative-cup-product-commute-with-restriction-operator).

Let $A$ and $B$ be subspaces of a space $X$, and let $X$ have a basepoint $* \in A \cap B$. How I deduce the following commutative diagram?$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
H^q(X, A) \otimes H^q(X, B) @>>> H^{p+q}(X, A \cup B)\\
@VVV     @VVV     \\
\overline{H}^p(X) \otimes \overline{H}^q(X) @>>> \overline{H}^{p+q}(X)
\end{CD}
$$For a based space $X$, the reduced cohomology of $X$ is defined to be$$\overline{E}^q(X) = E^q(X, *).$$We take cohomology with coefficients in a commutative ring $R$ and we write $\otimes$ for $\otimes_R$.

Comment: You can directly see it on the level of cochains, just like in the previous question... Do you understand the definitions of the objects involved?

Answer (score 0):

This is just the commutativity of the restriction maps with the cup product on the level of cochains combined with the fact that $\tilde{H}_\bullet(X) = H_\bullet(X, *)$.