# Cup product is the zero homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

Let $A$ and $B$ be subspaces of a space $X$. Let $X = A \cup B$, where $A$ and $B$ are contractible and $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$. How do I see that the cup product$$\tilde{H}^p(X) \otimes \tilde{H}^q(X) \to \tilde{H}^{p+q}(X)$$is the zero homomorphism? For a based space $X$, the reduced cohomology of $X$ is defined to be$$\tilde{E}^q(X) = E^q(X, *).$$We take cohomology with coefficients in a commutative ring $R$ and we write $\otimes$ for $\otimes_R$.

Answer (score 0):

From the commutative diagram [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537535/x-has-a-basepoint-in-a-cap-b-commuting-diagram-involving-relative-cup-p), $H_\bullet(X, A \cup B) = H_\bullet(X, X) = 0$, so if we can show the left arrow is surjective, we are done. However, on each factor, it is just a restriction map, so this is clearly the case.