# A theorem on fibre bundles, $H^k(E) \cong H^{k+n}(E,E_0)$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles

This is a theorem about fibre bundles, stated in [page 21, Theorem 3.6](http://web.math.ku.dk/~moller/students/mauricio.pdf)

> Let $\xi= (E,B,p)$ be an $n$-vector bundle. Let $F_0$ be the fibre $F$ without its nonzero element, and $E_0$ be the total space with out the zero section.
>
> The group $H^i(E,E_0; \Bbb Z_2)$ is zero for $i<n$ and $H^n(E,E_0; \Bbb Z_2)$ contains a unique class $u$ such that for each fibre $F= \pi^{-1}(b)$ the restriction, 
>       $$ u|(F,F_0)  \in H^n(F,F_0; \Bbb Z_2)$$
>       is the unique nonzero class in $H^n(F,F_0; \Bbb Z_2)$. **Furthermore, the correspondence $x \mapsto x \cup  u $ defines an isomoprhism 
>       $$ \cdot \cup u : H^k(E,\Bbb Z_2) \rightarrow H^{k+n}(E,E_0; \Bbb Z_2)$$**

My question is, how exactly is the last map (highlighted) defined?

---

My intuitive attempt: By definition an element in $H^{k+n}(E,E_0; \Bbb Z_2)$ is represented by some cocycle $u:C_{n}(E,E_0) \rightarrow \Bbb Z_2$.

This again lifts to an element, $u':C_{n}(E) \rightarrow \Bbb Z_2$. Hence we can define 
$$ x \cup u: C_{k+n}(E) \rightarrow  \Bbb Z_2$$
So it suffices to check this vanishes on $C_{k+n}(E_0)$, which does  as $u$ vanishes on $C_n(E_0)$. So we have an induced map $x \cup u:C_{k+n}(E,E_0) \rightarrow \Bbb Z_2$.

Now we then have a series of check: that this operation gives an element in cohomology class, and is well defined on cohomology class.

---

I think my argument (even if it is right) is extremely inefficient, is there a neat way to see this?

Comment: An argument will depend on your definition of the cup product (in particular, it will depend on which cohomology theory you  are using). For singular cohomology Hatcher gives a definition of the relative cup product on page 209 of *Algebraic Toplogy*. (See also, for instance, this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1536537/construction-of-a-relative-cup-product-hpx-a-otimes-hqx-b-to-hp-q)

Comment: Ok, thanks, yes, I am using the definition of Hatcher's, I will check out the post.